# Unable to ssh to google cloud instance which is created from the OVa

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

I have created a google cloud instance from the custom OVA by using the following command:

```
gcloud beta compute instances import instance --source-uri=gs://abc/xyz.ova --os=centos-7
```

In the VM which I used to create the OVA ssh is enabled on port 22.

Unfortunately, I am unable to ssh to the instance created. In gcp firewall ssh port 22 is enabled
I am getting the following error while trying to ssh.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

I couldn't get the exact reason.